# Nested custom components inside table rendered in the wrong place?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-table

I want to render a table, and as I would need to work on the cell, I define them through a component.

Below is the example in the fiddle:

```js
Vue.component('table-cell', {
    props: {
        'r': 0,
        'c': 0
    }, 
    template: '<td style="border: 1px solid black; width:2em;">{{ c }}</td>'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        rows: 3,
        cols: 3,
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="r in rows">
                <table-cell v-for="c in cols" v-bind:key="c">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But the generated code is not what I expected :

```html
<div id="app">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

For a reason I do not understand, my `td` elements are generated outside the `tr` ones, and everything seems to work as if my two loops were not nested. When I change the `<table-cell>` with simple `<td>` (not using a component), it works as expected.

Comment: Not an answer you're looking for, but I'd like to point out that the data property should be a function that returns an object

Comment: Is this not only true for components but not for vue instance ?

Comment: For both. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into an HTML parsing edge case which is described in the Vue docs under [HTML Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats). The workaround is to use the `is` attribute on custom components inside of `table`s. Here's a fixed working example of your code:

```js
Vue.component('table-cell', {
    props: {
        r: Number,
        c: Number,
    }, 
    template: '<td>{{r}}, {{c}}</td>',
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        rows: 3,
        cols: 3,
    },
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="r in rows" :key="r">
        <td is="table-cell" v-for="c in cols" :key="c" :r="r" :c="c">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>     
  </table>
</div>
```